# Sidebar menu doesn't show on Safari/IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed position navbar, and buttons that open a sidebar menu on mobile. Only on IOS and Safari the sidebar doesn't show when you click on cart or account. Obviously, it's some sort of compatibility issue, but how can I work around or fix this?

https://walkpop.com/

I've seen some other threads on StackOverflow say its because Webkit translate doesn't work inside a fixed position parent, so I removed translate all together from my code to avoid rearranging the HTML. Right now I'm using JS to change the left values from -10000px to 0 on click.

This was the code given to me, and it's a pain to rearrange the HTML because of the styling attached to everything.

On desktop and Android, the website works completely fine. Only on IOS and Safari does the sidebar pull out, but you can only see the top bit of the sidebar.
[Here is an image of the issue on IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLBnA.jpg)

Comment: I viewed your website on Chrome inspect element as iphone X device, it works fine. Please show screenshot or any other way to show where exactly it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheUnKnown It works fine on Chrome as Iphone, it only appears on actual Iphone devices or Safari on Mac. Will update with pictures in a sec

Comment: @TheUnKnown image here! http://i63.tinypic.com/30lfj15.png

Comment: Try to change your meta tag to `<meta content="width=640, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" name="viewport">` also please try to show minimal code so people can see what might be the problem.

Comment: @TheUnKnown http://i66.tinypic.com/rh8xll.png This is what happens after I changed it. It still isn't displaying properly

Comment: Please try to show minimal code so people can see what might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issues was caused because the parent element had a `overflow: hidden;` attribute. For some reason it was only hiding the sidebar on IOS. Once I removed that line, everything was fixed.